# Extract the text from <b></b> tags

Tags: python, html, regex, tags

I have the text (code for Python 2.6):

```
txt="foo<br><br><b>bar :</b><br>foo<br><b>bar :</b>"
```

Then I tried to extract the contents of any tag (<b> tag in this example):

```
r=re.compile("<%s.*?>(.+?)</%s>" % ("b","b"), re.I|re.S)
```

This mostly works, but the output is not what I've expected for my tricky text:

```
>>>re.findall(r,txt)
['<br><b>bar :', 'foo<br><b>bar :']
```

Is it possible to write one regular expression to extract the text from any HTML tag in any case?

Comment: Use html parser for this purpose like [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or [lxml](http://lxml.de/).

Comment: Your requirements aren't clear enough. I infer that you want to assume a closing *b* tag if the nesting would otherwise be illegal and assuming the closing tag would fix it? That is way beyond the reasonable use of regexps. You want a robust HTML tag parser instead. Luckily there are many of those.

Comment: @KurzedMetal: Any specific reason to use BeautifulSoup and not lxml.

Comment: @RanRag: Any reason to edit a comment? I just gave the OP the first option it came to my mind.

Comment: I rather like to use simple tool for a simple problem. Please note the <b> tags are not nested.

Comment: @KurzedMetal: Than its fine. I thought you gave that option for a reason. Personally I believe for a beginner BeautifulSoup is much better option.

Comment: @RanRag **anything** is better than regex to parse html. :P I actually found lxml useful to parse with xpath and beautifulsoup to iterate through web pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<=<b>).*?(?=<\/b>)
```

This regex pattern will get all text within the  tags.

http://regexr.com?30oga

Comment: YES! Thanks! This is exaclty I was looking for! I've come up with: re.compile("<%s(?=[ >\n]).*?>(.+?)</%s>" % ("b","b"), re.I|re.S) wich is basically the same idea.

Comment: NP, click on the check mark next to my answer if you like it.

Answer (score 3):

In general, you can't parse HTML with regex, because regex only captures, well, regular expression languages.  The HTML language contains arbitrary nestings, and regex cannot handle these.

That said, you can extract the text between open and close tags for typical html, if you just make one minor change to your regex code:

```
r=re.compile("<%s.*?>(.+?)</%s>" % ("b","b"), re.I|re.S)
```

```
>>> r=re.compile("<%s>(.+?)</%s>" % ("b","b"), re.I|re.S)
>>> txt="foo<br><br><b>bar :</b><br>foo<br><b>bar :</b>"
>>> re.findall(r, txt)
['bar :', 'bar :']
```

The .*? allows 
 to match your opening tag.

However, this strategy only matches the first tag matching your pattern to the *first* closing tag matching your pattern, not to the one that actually pairs with the open tag.  It will not do what you might expect when identical tags are nested, as in the following case:

```
>>> txt="foo<b><b><b>bar :</b></b></b><br>foo<br><b>bar :</b>"
>>> re.findall(r, txt)
['<b><b>bar :', 'bar :']
>>>
```

Comment: My +1 to the answer.  This is related to the language theory.  Nested structures cannot be parsed by regular expressions.  The extended regular expressions are actually a bit more powerful.  Still, using a decent parser is always better.

Answer (score 2):

As others pointed out, parsing HTML with regex ist usually not a good idea. I would suggest you use [htmllib](http://docs.python.org/library/htmllib.html). For instance:

```
import htmllib

class MyParser(htmllib.HTMLParser):     
  def __init__(self, fmt):
    htmllib.HTMLParser.__init__(self, fmt)        
    self.inb = False

  def start_b(self, data):
    self.inb = True

  def end_b(self):
    self.inb = False

  def handle_data(self, data):
    if self.inb: 
       #do sth with data
```

Comment: Its looks like that htmllib is depreciated http://docs.python.org/library/htmllib.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but I think this regex does what you want:

```
>>> re.findall(re.compile(r"<(\w+)>(.+?)</\1>", re.I|re.S), "foo<br><br><b>bar :</b><br>foo<br><b>bar :</b>")
[('b', 'bar :'), ('b', 'bar :')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Or BeautifulSoup (incredibly fast):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

txt="foo<br><br><b>bar :</b><br>foo<br><b>bar :</b>"
your_text = soup(txt)
for your in your_text:
    your_text = your.findAll('b')
    print your_text.text
```